# QMediaPlayer on windows xp (qt 5.3.1)

Tags: qt, windows-xp, qmediaplayer

the problema appears on Windows xp using QT 5.3.1.
Working with win7 the below code doesn't show anything on winxp.. I recompiled QT with xp support and I have under mediaservice also dsengine.dll but nothing change.

```
m_layout.addWidget(&m_vw);
m_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
ui.VideoWidget->setLayout(&m_layout);

m_player.setVideoOutput(&m_vw);

ui.VideoWidget->show();

m_playlist.addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("C:\\file.avi").absoluteFilePath()));
m_playlist.setCurrentIndex(1);
m_playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);

m_player.setPlaylist(&m_playlist);

...then play the video after press a button...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reported to qt support, seems to be a bug also in version 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is ../plugin/mediaservice uses wmfengine.dll which wanna use mf.dll;mfplat.dll;mfreadwrite.dll

the last are absent on your machine. If anybody knows package name, how to install it, you get the answer.

Radmir